# Raspian continuously reboots after reaching autologin console

Tags: raspbian, reboot

I'm a pretty experienced Raspberry Pi / Raspian / Raspberry OS user and can't figure this one out.

Background: I started encountering this issue about a month ago on two varieties: RPi4 and RPiZero2. I have RPiZero, RPi3B+ but have not seen this behavior on them. This has happened on about 5 of my 12 Pis. They run fine for about 2-3 days and then start rebooting continuously. I run virtually the same load on all my Pis (Debian Bullseye Legacy Lite and apps loaded by Ansible). I have tried the newer 64-bit Raspian load but saw the same behavior.

Symptom: After reaching the console (autologin at boot), the system reboots after about 2-3 seconds. No warning. Reboot takes about 15 seconds and it never stops. I think this may have destroyed one RPi4 and one RPiZero2W all I get now is a solid red LED on the RPi4 and a solid green LED on the RPi02. I'm using libcamera and the Pi Camera Module v3 on the ones that are having an issue.

Debugging so far: I've checked my logs for low voltage warnings (none) before the system starts reboot-cycling, but I can't get the system to run long enough to do much debug after this begins.

Any clues on how to debug under these conditions are appreciated.

Comment: Maybe try replacing an SD card on one of the problem units? It's *troubleshooting*... you've got to try different things to get some ideas.

Comment: `but I can't get the system to run long enough to do much debug after this begins` - there may be useful information in the logs - mount the drive in a pi that works (or any linux machine) and check the logs at your leisure

Comment: Thanks Seamus. Yes, tried replacing components. Memory card, cameras, camera cables, power supply, power supply cables. Odd thing is it occurs on all libcamera machines and ONLY the libcamera machines. Checked the libcamera forums, no clues.

Comment: Thanks Jaromanda. Yes, I used to be able to load on my Windows machines and mount but unsuccessful with Win11. I'll load up on a spare RPi4. Good suggestion.